# Add Service Reference Option for WCF Not Adding Everything to Proxy Classes

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, svcutil.exe

So I have a project I've inherited that has a WCF Service Reference and the corresponding `Reference.cs` generated proxy classes. In the ***existing*** proxy classes I can see an `enum` defintion:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="MyRecord.ColorAction", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DocumentsDataAccess.DataClasses")]
public enum ColorAction : int {

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    NONE = 0,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    GREEN = 1,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    RED = 2,

}
```

Here is the corresponding WCF code:

```
[DataContract]
public enum ColorAction
{
    [EnumMember]
    NONE = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    GREEN = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    RED = 2,
}
```

I can verify this is exposed by looking at the `wsdl` in a browser and I can see the `enum` types listed.

However, when I either 'refresh' or 'Add Service Reference' (as a new reference by deleting and re-adding), this `enum` along with a lot of other methods and enums are *missing*. The download and creation of the proxy classes is successful so it's not an issue of an error.

I have tried adjusting all of the 'Advanced' settings in the `Add Service Reference` dialog, but it seems to make no difference. The net result is since existing code is expecting to be able to call and use the `enums` among other code that's missing, the code will not compile after refreshing or re-adding the service reference.

I've already tried unchecking `Reuse types in all referenced assemblies` but that did not change the outcome.

I'm wondering, did the original person that created the proxy classes I'm looking at *not* use the `Add Service Reference` wizard and went directly to use `SvcUtil.exe` instead? I've used it before myself, but wondering is that what I need to use that will generate *everything* the WCF service is exposing? What switches would I need to get *everything* the service has to publicly offer? (FYI, I'm targeting .NET 4.0).

Comment: Are your enumeration members marked with the EnumMemberAttribute? What kind of application is your client?

Comment: See my updated code. `[EnumMember]` attribute exists.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the hosting WCF service code for the Enum class?

`Add Service Reference` may not create a complete reference file [SO-SvcUtil.exe vs Add Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402810/svcutil-exe-vs-add-reference).  It's possible that `SvcUtil.exe` was used instead.  Try that and see if that builds a better proxy.

Comment: Is the enum class used in any methods on the WCF side? It must be part of the contract - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098800/datacontract-for-enums-in-wcf)

Comment: Enums are pulled in using `Add Service Reference` in VS2010 but not in VS2012. Any idea on why the IDE change would create different proxies even though the same options were used to create them?

Comment: @atconway - Can you clarify what you mean 'pulled in VS2010 but not in VS2012"?  Any chance the project you inherited targeted an earlier FW, like 3.5?  When you unchecked "Reuse types in all referenced assemblies" did you then select the corresponding assemblies you needed?

Comment: By pulled in I mean 'created in the proxy classes'. So in VS2010 the enums were created in the proxy classes but not in the proxy classes in VS2012 using the _exact_ same options in the `Add Service Reference` dialog. I didn't check any of the assemblies in either version of VS.NET after deselecting 'Reuse...'

Comment: Try hand selecting the assemblies.  Can you compare the reference.cs files between the original and your refreshed version.  Are there any diffs?  Are the namespaces intact?